# "Module not found" when migrating to Webpack 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, backbone.js, babeljs

I am trying to migrate my React app to webpack 5.72.0 (from 4.42.1). So I also have webpack-cli (4.9.2), webpack-dev-server (4.8.1) and babel (7.17.9).

My problem is as follows. When I build my project, I get the following error :

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 9:13-11:11
Module not found: Error: path argument is not a string
```

(this is a simplified version - in reality, I get about 56 of these!)

I believe this to be due to my use of Magic Comments in imports but I can't figure out why...

UPDATE: It's actually due to Backbone. If I "magically" import anything else (that doesn't use Backbone) it works fine. However with Backbone (as per the index.js below), I get the error above. I believe there might be some conflict with the import-loader used in the webpack config but I'm not sure how to resolve this...

UPDATE: Added a simple version to GitHub on the off-chance some kind soul would have 5 min to take a look ... https://github.com/ChambreNoire/backbone-issue

Below is my setup. Any ideas?

Cheers!

src/index.js (simplified)

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const root = document.getElementById('content')

Promise.all([
    import(/*webpackChunkName:"backbone"*/'backbone'),
]).then((modules) => {
    render(<div>Test</div>, root)
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app-ui",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.17.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.17.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.16.7",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.17.9",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.5",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "10.2.4",
    "copyfiles": "2.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.22.3",
    "css-loader": "6.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "5.5.0",
    "imports-loader": "3.1.1",
    "jest": "28.0.2",
    "jest-junit": "13.2.0",
    "less": "4.1.2",
    "less-loader": "10.2.0",
    "style-loader": "3.3.1",
    "url-loader": "4.1.1",
    "webpack": "5.72.0",
    "webpack-cli": "4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.8.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "~1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "~5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "~5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "~0.1.9",
    "@juggle/resize-observer": "^3.2.0",
    "antd": "^4.17.3",
    "backbone": "~1.4.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "classnames": "~2.2.6",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "d3-array": "^2.9.1",
    "d3-axis": "^2.0.0",
    "d3-drag": "^2.0.0",
    "d3-force": "^2.1.1",
    "d3-hierarchy": "^2.0.0",
    "d3-scale": "^3.2.3",
    "d3-selection": "^2.0.0",
    "d3-shape": "^2.0.0",
    "d3-transition": "^2.0.0",
    "d3-zoom": "^2.0.0",
    "event-source-polyfill": "~1.0.15",
    "i18next": "~19.4.4",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.0.18",
    "moment": "~2.24.0",
    "prop-types": "~15.7.2",
    "rc-resize-observer": "^0.2.6",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^12.0.1",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-i18next": "~11.4.0",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "~1.5.8",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^1.11.0",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "typeface-roboto": "~0.0.75",
    "underscore": "~1.9.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0",
    "which-browser": "^0.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "run-dev": "webpack serve --config config/webpack/webpack.dev.js",
  }
}
```

config/webpack/webpack.dev.js

```
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const {IgnorePlugin} = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const paths = require('../paths')
const {appOutput, appSrc, appHtml, appIndex} = paths

module.exports = {
    stats: {
        errorDetails: true
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: false,
    entry: appIndex,
    output: {
        filename: 'app.[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash].chunk.js',
        path: appOutput
    },
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            fs: false,
            crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'), // polyfill for which-browser
            buffer: require.resolve('buffer/'),
            stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                use: 'url-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'less-loader',
                        options: {
                            lessOptions: {
                                javascriptEnabled: true,
                                modifyVars: {
                                    'menu-collapsed-width': '64px'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /backbone\.js$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        options: {
                            loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false',
                        },
                    }
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        host: HOST,
        port: PORT,
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        client: {
          logging: 'verbose'
        },
        static: appOutput,
        setupMiddlewares: middlewares => {
            openBrowser && openBrowser(`http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
            return middlewares;
        },
        onListening: devServer => {
            if (!devServer) {
                throw new Error('webpack-dev-server is not defined');
            }
            const port = devServer.server.address().port;
            console.log('Listening on port:', port);
        },
        proxy: {
            '/resources': {
                target: 'http://localhost:9001',
                cookiePathRewrite: '/'
            },
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: appSrc + '/unavailable.html' },
                { from: appSrc + '/401.html' },
                { from: appSrc + '/asset', to: 'asset' },
            ],
        }),
        new IgnorePlugin({
            resourceRegExp: /^jquery$/
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: appHtml
        }),
        new SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            append: '\n//# sourceMappingURL=[url]',
            filename: '[name].js.map'
        })
    ]
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      useBuiltIns: "usage",
      corejs: 3
    }],
    "@babel/react"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try writing one magic comment with the correct syntax to see if that fixed the error for that import? Like this `/* webpackChunkName: "backbone" */ 'backbone'`.

Comment: @morganney As per my last edit it looks like it is actually due to Backbone and a possible conflict with import-loader but I'm not sure how to resolve this...

Answer (score 0):

I think your error might be coming from this line of code

```
{
  test: /backbone\.js$/,
  use: [
    {
      options: {
        loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false',
      },
    }
  ],
}
```

Maybe try

```
{
  test: /backbone\.js$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false',
      options: {},
    }
  ],
}
```

I don't think you're loading the loader properly